# GTest launched through colcon gets SEGFAULT

Tags: googletest, ros2, colcon

I'm  using `colcon` to run tests for my **ROS2** application.
Up until now I haven't had any problems, but now after adding a simple fixture

```cpp
class ElectionTest : public ::testing::Test {
    protected:
        ElectionModule core_;
};
```

and relative tests it seems like the underlying GTest is crashing: in the test summary I see

```
[ RUN      ] ElectionTest.CantPrepareTopics
-- run_test.py: return code -11
-- run_test.py: generate result file '/home/slim71/Documents/git/SpartanLIFT/build/pelican/test_results/pelican/pelican_test.gtest.xml' with failed test
-- run_test.py: verify result file '/home/slim71/Documents/git/SpartanLIFT/build/pelican/test_results/pelican/pelican_test.gtest.xml'
```

and everything stops of course. Code `-11` should be `SEGFAULT`, which I don't know where is coming from.

Introducing some `cout` here and there I can see that the crash happens after calling the object destructor, but then I don't know what the problem can be.
If the `ElectionModule` destructor is being called before the test ends, my guess is that there's no problem with my class...

Is there any way to debug or find out more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, my "guess" was wrong!
It was indeed due to my code (which to be honest is always the most probable explanation): there was indeed some problem in the *use of pointers*, so it would have been better if I shared at least parts of it..

To be precise, in case anybody else stumbles in this: it seemed like something out of my code because it was the invoked at the very end of the destructor. I was using `RCLCPP_DEBUG_STREAM` with an empty pointer to `rclcpp::Logger`. I had added a boolean check, aka `if(logger_)`, but since `logger_` wasn't initialized to a `nullptr` I guess here and there the boolean conversion passed and the code tried to access some protected memory. **Definitely my bad!**

The most useful thing I got from this, which I'll share just in case, is how to correctly debug the **ROS2** executable used by `colcon test`:

1. Be sure to compile the executable *with debug info*, i.e. by adding `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)` in the *CMakeLists.txt*.
2. Get the path to the compiled executable (for example, you can manually launch `colcon test`and inspect the summary, like I did)
3. Just launch that executable in the debugger with the appropriate command! I've used `gdbtui /path/to/test_exe`

Well, I guess the loss in reputation is what I get from this! ¯_(ツ)_/¯